# livenessprobe exec check probe for mongodb is killing pod under k8s 1.2.4

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-health-check

I'm trying to implement livenessProbes on pods running under K8s.
Only very simple probe is working, see example:

```
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /etc/services
      initialDelaySeconds: 45
      timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Probe I need to implement is killing pod every 50sec.

```
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
          mongo --port 27018 --eval "rs.status()"  | grep  "REMOVED" ; test $? -eq 1
      initialDelaySeconds: 45
      timeoutSeconds: 5
```

When probe is not implemented and command run inside a pod it is returning 1 if REMOVED string found and 0 if not found as required.

*[root@eas-mongo-rs-3-ui81p /]# mongo --port 27018 --eval "rs.status()"  | grep  "REMOVED" ; test $? -eq 1*

Question is, how to implement such command as Container Exec Check.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your command will be quoted and not run as you think, if you want to use pipelines and other more advanced shell functionalities, you can use `/bin/sh`, a workaround you can also see in the official documentation.

So your probe would look something like this:

```
 livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - mongo --port 27018 --eval "rs.status()" | grep -vq "REMOVED"
  initialDelaySeconds: 45
  timeoutSeconds: 5
```

You can also use the `-v` switch to grep to avoid the reversing of the status with that extra `test` command.